# Direction of Friction Force of a box on a moving truck ( question is different and not as advanced, focused on a situation )

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, friction, free-body-diagram

If there is a box on a truck. The truck is accelerating to the right. The question asks us to draw all forces applying on the **box**. (Free body diagram of the box)

I have done this, but I always read that friction is opposite to the direction of motion. But when I read in other places the static friction that is holding the box and the truck together is in the direction of the truck. Can you please check if I am right? Thank you.

[image]

It is not the same question, it is more simple in nature, those answers are not clear bearing this question in mind. Thank you.

Comment: *"I always read that friction is opposite to the direction of motion"* There is a crucial word missing in there. Hopefully most of your sources have it and you just didn't realize how important it is, but if not you want to find a source that does.

Comment: Sir, Can you please advise me about that word. You can also point a link and I can study myself. I am almost sure of my work, but not a 100%. This will help me understand.

Comment: @KudmiSubba do not confuse friction between the box and truck with friction between the truck and the ground

Comment: @XcoderX - Sir, Thank you, you have been very kind. I am trying to learn this clearly and hence the simple questions.

Comment: Friction is not so much about motion but more about *sliding*. Friction always pulls in the direction that tries to prevent or stop sliding. Both truck and box move rightwards here, but which way would the box slide if it started sliding? Which way does friction then have to hold back in order to prevent that box from sliding?

Comment: @Steeven , How do I accept an answer for this, I am not sure the other question is directly related to this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: There should be an "accept" button next to each answer. Have a look at the intro for the site and it should be clear how to use it

Comment: The crucial word is "relative". Friction prevents or resists *relative* motion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the truck is accelerating to the right, and hence the body feels a *pseudo-force* in the opposite direction, i.e, in the *left* direction, in a reference frame ***fixed to the truck***.

If you have convinced yourself up to this, then consider the body-truck interface. The body has a tendency to slide in the left direction, as the pseudo-force on it tends to drive it to the left.

Now the crucial point. **Friction always acts in the direction so as to resist the *relative* sliding between the two surfaces in contact**. As the body feels a force to the left, the static friction, which  holds the body in its place, must act to the *right*, to maintain equilibrium.

Hence, you must take into account the relative sliding between the two bodies in contact. Though the truck along with the body is moving in the right direction, you should judge the situation from a reference frame *fixed on the truck*. Then you can efficiently judge the *relative* motion between the truck and the body. But you are judging from the *ground reference frame*, in which the body is also accelerating to the *right* along with the truck. That's what ran you in confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is friction works most of the time opposite to the direction of Motion but not always in this situation when the truck is accelerating in forward direction there will be tendency of motion between the truck and the block and so since there is tendency of motion between them so the block will exert a friction force on the block in the left direction which will oppose the motion of truck
But there is one more interesting thing due to Newton's third law there will be equal and opposite force on the block in forward direction. So see in this case is actually responsible for the motion where you will use your equation of Motion as friction=mass of block*(acc)

Comment: I want to thank everyone for their patience in explaining this concept so well.